# Как организовать такой функционал на selenoid?

Tags: веб-программирование, selenium, тестирование, test-automation, selenium-grid

Простите, я новичок в тестировании, если это может не коректний вопрос. Мне надо реализовать такой функционал- в приложение приходит запрос и мы на этот запрос запускаем тест selenoid или jsonwire-grid тест и в этот тест предаем какие-то даннные типа пароль и логин которий нужно ввести в тесте. Дальше он удалено выполнился и вернул результат приложению(все ок или ошибка) Сам тест виполняется около получаса. Сказать честно, вобще непонимаю как такое реализовать поскольку нету нормальних туториалов как все ето настроить и запустить.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium GRID состоит из хаба и нод (узлов). Node это просто java-процесс. Он может быть и на одной машине с Hub, может быть на другой машине, может быть в Docker контейнере. Hub — это по сути балансировщик для автотестов, определяющий узел, на какой следует отправить выполнение конкретного теста. К нему можно подключить и мобильные эмуляторы.

Comment: Что мешает сделать запуск теста на post запрос?